# Can I get information about IPR, PGR or ANDA litigation?

Tags: ipr, pgr, anda

I am considering invalidation trials in Japan regarding certain patent rights.
I would like to know if corresponding US patent was already fought in the United States and what kind of evidence or assertion was made in IPR, PGR or ANDA litigation.
Are there any database or site which allow us to view the information of IPR, PGR or ANDA litigation.

Answer (score 1):

You need the US patent numbers of all family members for the japanese patents you are interested in (espacenet for example should have them).

You can then find the data about IPRs at the Patent Trial and Appeal Board website:

https://ptabdataui.uspto.gov/#/documents

I think there is also a ptab database for litigation, but I don't know if it's complete or just some examples.

There are commercial sites that get you all the information about US litigation, IPRs etc. if you just enter the japanese patent number, but free sites with some information, too.

For example:
https://www.patexia.com/lawsuits/AOL-Inc-v-Chan-id-74036
https://search.rpxcorp.com/lit/dedce-59959-improved-search-v-microsoft

(Just some random lawsuit as an example).

You will have to pay for the documents normally (15ct. per page or sth like that up to $3 per document), but the official source where you can get the dockets (PACER) costs money too and registering is easier with these pages afaik.